# StringLengthAttribute In Model (12 || null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I want to add validation for a field in my model that either can be empty or 12 characters. I want something like the code below, how can i do this?

```
    [UIOMaticListViewField]        
    [StringLength(0 || 12)]
    [UIOMaticField(Name = "Video Title", Description = "Enter Video Title", View = UIOMatic.Constants.FieldEditors.Textfield, Tab = "Content", TabOrder = 1)]
    public string VideoTitle { get; set; }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke But then it can be between 0-12. I want it to be empty or 12

Comment: Sorry, did not read your question correctly. Use a `[RegularExpression]` that specifies it must be 12 character exactly (if the value of the textbox is null, then your regex is ignored)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks will take a look at that!

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{12}$` should do it (and `0-9` if you want to allow digits as well)

Comment: `[StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 12)]` should also work (not tested)

Comment: @StephenMuecke still cant get the null input to work, tried {12 null} {12}{null} and also replace null with 0 but cant get it to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165630/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-patte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 12)]
```

or if you want a bit more control over what characters are permitted, you can use a `RegularExpressionAttribute`, for example, to allow exactly 12 upper or lower case characters

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]{12}$")]
```

By default, validation attributes (except `[Required]`) pass validation if the value is `null`, so you do not need additional checks for `null` values.